# Using other ORM libraries alongside entity framework core for querying

Tags: sql, linq, orm, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I would like to have statically typed LINQ expressions that produce SQL to be executed on the database. Unfortunately it seems entity framework core is very limited with regards to `union` and `group by`. Is it possible to use another library, e.g. LINQ-to-SQL purely for querying, that uses the statically typed entity classes we already have rather than hand-crafting SQL?

Comment: You might take a look at [LINQ to DB](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db#linq-to-db) which seems (or is supposed) to be doing what you need.

Comment: Union will come in EF Core 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've settled for using [LINQ to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474038/using-other-orm-libraries-alongside-entity-framework-core-for-querying#comment101422882_57474038) thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474038/using-other-orm-libraries-alongside-entity-framework-core-for-querying#comment101422882_57474038).

We're using the same entity classes we use for entity framework for the queries, and to ensure the table names are correct we use the C# `nameof` operator, e.g. `nameof(EFContext.UserTasks)`. This should allow us to be fairly sure our queries still work even after renaming properties/tables.